# libgdx gradle - forgot to make android project

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx

I set up my libgdx projects with HTML5 and Desktop, but later decided to add Android support. How do I add the Android project?

I'm afraid if I use the setup UI again it'll overwrite my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setup-ui once more with exactly the same parameters like you did when you were initially creating the projects, *but* use another destination folder. Then re-create all of them again.

When you are done with that, copy the `android` folder to your original projects. You will also need to copy some of the single files in the root folder. Those are `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle`. If you have changed your `build.gradle` file manually already, you should only copy the part for the android project to the original file instead of replacing it.

After that you should re-import all the projects into your IDE once more.